# Node JS Save Multiple Records to Mongo in single 'transaction'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, factory

Please could you advise me on the best way to solve a problem that I am facing? I know that there are many ways to skin a cat. I have tried many different ways but cannot seem to find a solution.

In summary:

My node js application has a get request. When a user hits this GET URL, I want it to get the records for this user, however, if there are none, I want to create a set of records for this user according to a pre-defined list. (I need something like a *factory* to create a batch or records and give the results when it is done.)

Creating a single record works. But I need to create 4. If I try to create more than one I get ...

**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client** or just a plain error depending on which variation I use.

Basically, as soon as you create more than 1 record, the creation of that record returns a response - which I would like to 'combine' and when done send the combined result back.

My model is very simple. It looks like this:

```
/*____             _        _     __  __           _      _ 
 |  _ \           | |      | |   |  \/  |         | |    | |
 | |_) |_   _  ___| | _____| |_  | \  / | ___   __| | ___| |
 |  _ <| | | |/ __| |/ / _ \ __| | |\/| |/ _ \ / _` |/ _ \ |
 | |_) | |_| | (__|   <  __/ |_  | |  | | (_) | (_| |  __/ |
 |____/ \__,_|\___|_|\_\___|\__| |_|  |_|\___/ \__,_|\___|_|
*/
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dbSchema = mongoose.Schema;

const bucketSchema = new dbSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: false
    },
    createdby: {
        type: dbSchema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    createdon: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    isforarchive: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    },
    cards: [
        {
            card: {
                type: dbSchema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'card'
            }
        }
    ]
});

module.exports = bucket = mongoose.model('bucket', bucketSchema);
```

This code works when I create a single record. However, I need to create 4 buckets for the user :- ToDo, Busy, Done and Archive.

The code below WORKS BUT ONLY CREATES A SINGLE BUCKET - ToDo.

```
const ToDo = new Bucket({
    name: 'To-Do',
    createdby: null,
    createdon: Date.now(),
    isforarchive: false,
    cards: [ {} ]
});

// @route get:/api/tms/buckets
// @desc Gets user buckets or creates a set of buckets for the user if they do not exist.
// @access Private
router.get(
    '/',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {
        session: false
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log('About to search buckets...');
        Bucket.find({ createdby: req.user.id })
            .then((found) => {
                console.log('Checking if found');
                console.log(`Length ${found.length}`); // Zero when none found
                if (found.length > 0) {
                    res.json(found);
                } else {
                    console.log('Creating ToDo');
                    ToDo.createdby = req.user.id;
                    ToDo.save().then((saved) => res.json(saved));
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                const errors = {};
                errors.getbuckets = 'Encountered a problem getting buckets.';
                errors.error = err;
                res.status(400).json(errors);
            });
    }
);
```

To try and help me, I created a helper class ./buckethelper.js to assist me. I have tried promises etc but cannot work around the issue of the creation of the first record sending a response that causes the error above.

I have tried a number of different options in  my helper class which I cannot get to work. Therre are a number of issues that I have tried get around, one of which was I wanted the code to run synchronously and in series - not parallel.

Here is my helper class.

```
const Bucket = require('./model');
/*
//PLEASE NOTE THAT THIS SECTION IS COMMENTED OUT.
function CreateBucket(Name, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, IsForArchive, Cards) {
    this.name = Name;
    this.createdby = CreatedBy;
    this.createdon = CreatedOn;
    this.isforarchive = IsForArchive;
    this.cards = Cards;
}

const Buckets = [];
Buckets.push(new CreateBucket('To-Do', '', Date.now(), false, [ {} ]));
Buckets.push(new CreateBucket('Busy', '', Date.now(), false, [ {} ]));
Buckets.push(new CreateBucket('Done', '', Date.now(), false, [ {} ]));
Buckets.push(new CreateBucket('Archive', '', Date.now(), true, [ {} ]));
*/
const ToDo = new Bucket({
    name: 'To-Do',
    createdby: null,
    createdon: Date.now(),
    isforarchive: false,
    cards: [ {} ]
});
const Busy = new Bucket({
    name: 'Busy',
    createdby: null,
    createdon: Date.now(),
    isforarchive: false,
    cards: [ {} ]
});
const Done = new Bucket({
    name: 'Done',
    createdby: null,
    createdon: Date.now(),
    isforarchive: false,
    cards: [ {} ]
});
const Archive = new Bucket({
    name: 'Archive',
    createdby: null,
    createdon: Date.now(),
    isforarchive: true,
    cards: [ {} ]
});



var result = [];

function fnSaveToDo(UserId) {
    console.log(`Saving To Do ...`);
    ToDo.createdby = UserId;
    result.push(Bucket.save(ToDo));
}

function fnSaveBusy(UserId) {
    Busy.createdby = UserId;
    result.push(Bucket.insert(Busy));
}

function fnSaveDone(UserId) {
    Done.createdby = UserId;
    result.push(Bucket.insert(Done));
}

function fnSaveArchive(UserId) {
    Archive.createdby = UserId;
    result.push(Bucket.insert(Archive));
    return result;//I want to return the combined results
}

//Synchronous call stack that execute in series not parallel
function CreateBuckets(UserId, fnSaveToDo, fnSaveBusy, fnSaveDone, fnSaveArchive) {
    console.log('Started the saving process ...');
    fnSaveToDo(UserId);
    fnSaveBusy(UserId);
    fnSaveDone(UserId);
    fnSaveArchive(UserId);
 }
 CreateBuckets(
    function() {
        console.log('User id callback?');
    },
    function() {
        console.log('ToDo saved ...');
    },
    function() {
        console.log('Busy saved ...');
    },
    function() {
        console.log('Done saved ...');
    },
    function() {
        console.log('Archive saved ...');
    }
 );

 module.exports = CreateBuckets;
```

The code that calls my helper looks something like this, it's a subset of the code above;

```
Bucket.find({ createdby: req.user.id })
            .then((found) => {
                console.log('Checking if found');
                console.log(`Length ${found.length}`); // Zero when none found
                if (found.length > 0) {
                    res.json(found);
                } else {
                    //console.log('Creating ToDo');
                    res.json(CreateBuckets(req.user.id,fnSaveToDo,fnSaveBusy, fnSaveDone, fnSaveArchive));
                    // ToDo.createdby = req.user.id;
                    // ToDo.save().then((saved) => res.json(saved));    
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                const errors = {};
                errors.getbuckets = 'Encountered a problem getting buckets.';
                errors.error = err;
                res.status(400).json(errors);
            });
```

I hope that my descripton of the problem has been clear.

If or when I find a solution, I will post it. Been at this for a few days now without any success.

Kind regards
Craig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your solution. I could not however get *await* to work. Here is my solution. I will refactor it but it works.

```
const DefaultBuckets = [ 'To Do', 'Busy', 'Done', 'Archive' ];

// @route get:/api/tms/buckets
// @desc Gets user buckets or creates a set of buckets for the user if they do not exist.
// @access Private
router.get(
    '/',
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {
        session: false
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        console.log('About to search buckets...');
        Bucket.find({ createdby: req.user.id })
            .then((found) => {
                console.log('Checking if found');
                console.log(`Length ${found.length}`); // Zero when none found
                if (found.length > 0) {
                    console.log('returning what is in db');
                    res.json(found);
                } else {
                    // console.log('Creating buckets ...');
                    const defaults = DefaultBuckets.map((name) => ({
                        name,
                        createdby: req.user.id,
                        createdon: Date.now(),
                        isforarchive: name == 'Archive',
                        cards: [ {} ]
                    }));
                    Bucket.insertMany(defaults, (err, docs) => {
                        let errors = {};
                        // Docs are the saved records from the db
                        if (docs) {
                            res.json(docs);
                        }else{
                            errors.message = 'Could not create buckets';
                            errors.InsertMany = err;
                            res.status(400).json(errors);
                        }                   
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                const errors = {};
                errors.getbuckets = 'Encountered a problem getting buckets.';
                errors.error = err;
                res.status(400).json(errors);
            });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[`insertMany`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany)** method here to do a bulk insert and leverage async/await in your operations since the method returns a promise.

For instance, you route could be re-written as

```
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false }), async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log('About to search buckets...');
        const found = await Bucket.find({ createdby: req.user.id })

        console.log('Checking if found');
        console.log(`Length ${found.length}`); // Zero when none found
        if (found.length > 0) {
            res.json(found);
        } else {
            console.log('Creating ToDos');
            const todos = ['To-Do', 'Busy', 'Done', 'Archive'].map(name => (
                {
                    name,
                    createdby: req.user.id,
                    createdon: Date.now(),
                    isforarchive: (name == 'Archive'),
                    cards: [ {} ]
                }
            ));
            const saved = await ToDo.insertMany(todos);
            res.json(saved);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        const errors = {};
        errors.getbuckets = 'Encountered a problem getting buckets.';
        errors.error = err;
        res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
});
```